# Filling the action area of a gtk.Dialog window with its buttons - instead of having them aligned to the right

Tags: python, dialog, gtk, pygtk

Using PyGTK, I create a bunch of buttons in the action area of a `gtk.Dialog` using the `add_button()` method, as below:

```
self.replace_all_button = self.add_button(_("Replace All"), 
            gtk.RESPONSE_ACCEPT)
```

The resulting dialog has all the buttons aligned to the right, as seen in the following image:

[image: gtk.Dialog with action buttons aligned to the right]

However, I want to fill the action area with the buttons, just like in this image:

[image]

I have tried some curious strategies, such as to redefine the packing parameters of all widgets from the action area, as seen in the code below, but it did not work.

```
def redefine_packing(widget):
    _, _, padding, _ = self.action_area.query_child_packing(widget)
    self.action_area.set_child_packing(widget, True, True, padding, _)

self.action_area.foreach(redefine_packing)
```

How could I do it? (A solution does not need to be written in Python if I can intuitively translate it from the original language, which I usually can do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was "solved" when I discovered I was looking for a nonexistent problem.

I am trying to copying the look-and-feel fo the Gedit search and replace window. Then I started Gedit using the "C" locale and the search and replace dialog looked like this:

[image: Search and replace dialog with labels in English]

So the dialog I am trying to copy is just like the dialog I have. The original dialog I was looking at seemed different just because its labels were in a different language and were bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could replace the `hbuttonbox` in the dialog with a normal `hbox` and then more easily control the packing.

Comment: As my own anser makes it clear, the problem I was trying to solve was not what I was looking for. OTOH I found it very useful to know that the action area is not a mere gtk.HBox but a [`gtk.HButtonBox`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkbuttonbox.html#method-gtkbuttonbox--set-child-secondary), which was a class I not even knew to exist. Thank you!